# How to programmatically add a "region" to the "addresInformation" on the page of the "checkout" when ordering?

Tags: magento2

In my module, I add custom drop-down lists with states, cities and postal codes. Everything works well, but as soon as I select the US from the "Country" list, the data for "shippingAddress" and "billingAddress" change and "region" disappear.
Can you please tell us how you can programmatically add "region" when placing an order?

[image]